# Gradle plugin build pulls in wrong version of commons-io

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

What appears to be happening is that `compileJava` pulls in `commons-io-1.4.jar` from the gradle distribution, in preference to my declared `commons-io:commons-io:2.4`. When I try to call a method (`readLines(InputStream, Charset)`) introduced in a later version, Gradle can't find it:

```
$ gradle compileJava
:compileJava
/home/dmoles/Projects/m12n-plugins/tools/m12n/multiproject-plugin/src/main/java/m12n/tools/multiproject/dependencies/DependencyExtractor.java:42: error: no suitable method found for readLines(ByteArrayInputStream,Charset)
            List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()), Charsets.UTF_8);
                                        ^
    method IOUtils.readLines(Reader) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method IOUtils.readLines(InputStream,String) is not applicable
      (actual argument Charset cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
    method IOUtils.readLines(InputStream) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The `dependencies` section of my `build.gradle` (abbreviated):

```
dependencies {
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
  compile gradleApi()
  compile localGroovy()
}
```

`gradle dependencies` shows the right thing:

```
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
```

Obviously in this specific case I can work around it by calling the older method, but is there a general fix for this? I don't want to have to individually track down every time I happen to use a library that's also used by Gradle itself.

Comment: `gradle dependencies` command should show both dependencies and the that is used is marked with `*`. Have You checked that? Have You tried to exclude the problematic dependency in some way? I also suppose that it's not possible, because of the fact that `gradle` needs this dependency itself.

Comment: Yes, there's no evidence of the wrong version in `gradle dependencies`. Possibly it's one of those cases where you get gradle's own classpath whether you want it or not.

Comment: Yes exactly. I had similar problem with guava. I've just copied the method I needed to an utility class.